# regular expression string replacement

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a url like this:

```
 http://mywebsite.com/my-very-long-product-title/my_sku,default,pd.html
```

I want to replace this string with

```
http://mywebsite.com/-/my_sku,default,pd.html
```

I'm using javascript only.  The rule is I want to always replace everything between the single slashes closest to the end of the string.

Comment: Check the latest edit in response to your own edit. It should do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED to match your question edit**

Okay, since this is in the regex category, I'll give a regex answer:

```
var text = 'http://mywebsite.com/my-very-long-product-title/my_sku,default,pd.html';
var re = '/(http:\/\/.+\/)[^\/]+?(\/.+)/i';
text.replace(re,'$1-$2');
```

Or are you talking about making anything going to `http://mywebsite.com/-/my_sku,default,pd.html` load the same data as `http://mywebsite.com/my-very-long-product-title/my_sku,default,pd.html`? - because that's a very different question indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to replace that exact same string, you can do this:

```
new_string = old_string.replace(/my-very-long-product-title/, '-');
```

If you want to replace whatever comes after `mywebsite.com/`, do something like:

```
new_string = old_string.replace(/(mywebsite.com\/)[^\/]+/, '$1-');
```

Or maybe, to make sure you don't replace stuff in a string like `http://mywebsite.com/whatever/mywebsite.com/this-shouldnt-be-replaced/etc`, do this:

```
new_string = old_string.replace(/^(http:\/\/mywebsite.com\/)[^\/]+/, '$1-');
```

Also, it's always good to accept `http` and `https`:

```
new_string = old_string.replace(/^(https?:\/\/mywebsite.com\/)[^\/]+/, '$1-');
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace everything from the second-to-last slash to the last slash with `/-/`, you can use

```
result = subject.replace(/\/[^\/]*\/(?=[^\/]*$)/g, "/-/");
```

More readable:

```
/           # Slash
[^/]*       # followed by any number of non-slash characters
/           # and another slash.
(?=[^/]*$)  # Make sure that there is no further slash until the end of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var oldUrl = "http://mywebsite.com/my-very-long-product-title/my_sku,default,pd.html";
var groups = /^(.*?com\/).*(\/.*)$/.exec(oldUrl);
var newUrl = groups[1] + "-" + groups[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer - like Tim Pietzcker's without using a lookahead.

```
find:      /[^/]*(/[^/]*)$
replace:   /-$1
```